# MongoDb insert data to different DBs based on request SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

[image: Model admin database structure]Hi I have mongoDb database which contains separate db for different shops, but the collections inside all the dbs have same structure, when I get the request from post service I want to insert the data to the respective database based in the id in the request. Please advice how to do this in springboot java or Kotlin

```
AMAZON 
  - ProductDetails
FLIPKART
  - ProductDetails
EBAY
  - ProductDetails
```

Now I have a single database and insert all product details in a single database and I want to add different databases for different shops

```
 spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
 spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
 spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
 spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
 spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
 spring.data.mongodb.database=admin
```

Comment: Create different entities (documents) for different users ,create different repositories implementing  MongoRepository Interface ,create different services and service Impls ,call them in your controller accordingly.

Comment: your question is not very clear. What are you planning to insert in database - collection or document? Also you mentioned in the comment that if the user is new, a new database will be created in MongoDB. Are you sure?

Comment: @Akash I have edited the question, I get details of products from different websites, I have to store the product details in the respective database based on the shop name.

Comment: @Akash please check the updated question

Comment: @Mohanraj there are at least one way of doing this is by checking whether the collection exists or not. If not, create a new collection with the shop name. Based on your properties, I assume you want to do like this now - **DB** - shop, **collections in DB** - Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay, Myntra etc., Inside collections, you can create or update documents for given request id (should be same as collection).

Comment: @Akash I have connected to admin database which has access to all databases, I want to change the default database (shop) of the MongoRepository based the request and insert the data

Comment: Do not create/change databases until it is required. Keep all the similar collections inside one DB. In your case, separate collections for each may not be required as well. Create documents with shop name (e.g. Amazon, Flipkart) and product name as key and you'll avoid a lot of complications.

Comment: I'll try to post sample code for both the approaches in few minutes. You can check that.

Comment: @Akash Databases will be created automatically.. I just want to insert the product inside the respective database. i.e. change the database of the default MongoRepository before inserting

Comment: @Akash I had attached the admin database which contains multiple databases, in this I have to insert in the respective database based on the request

Comment: @Mohanraj https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb check this out. It is very old but may be of some help. It looks to exactly match your requirements.

Comment: @Akash I saw this, but I don't know where and how to implement this.. I'm new to springboot and mongodb

Comment: No problem!  I'll try to provide you where to start in the answer.

Comment: @Mohanraj - If you have not got a proper solution, Check out the solution I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to Spring boot and MongoDB, I am providing you the detailed steps as follows to connect multiple mongo DB in single application. This is one of the most simple ways to configure and connect multiple mongo DB. Hopefully, it will be helpful (don't forget to vote up if it is :-)) -

**1) Package Structure -**

[image]

**2) Create an abstract MongoDB Config class -**

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.config;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

/**
 * Abstract class for configuring different MongoTemplate for different DB
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
public abstract class AbstractMongoDbConfig {

    private String host;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String database;
    private int port;

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {

        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), mongoCredential, new MongoClientOptions.Builder().build());

        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, database);
    }

    public abstract MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception;

}
```

**3) Extend the abstract class to create configuration for each DB**

AmazonDbConfig

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

/**
 * Configuration class for Amazon DB
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="amazon.mongodb")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.amazon"}, mongoTemplateRef="amazonMongoTemplate")
public class AmazonDbConfig extends AbstractMongoDbConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmazonDbConfig.class);

    @Override
    @Bean(name="amazonMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Creating MongoTemplate for Amazon DB");
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

EbayDbConfig

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

/**
 * Configuration class for ebay DB
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ebay.mongodb")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.ebay"}, mongoTemplateRef="ebayMongoTemplate")
public class EbayDbConfig extends AbstractMongoDbConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EbayDbConfig.class);

    @Override
    @Bean(name="ebayMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Creating MongoTemplate for Ebay DB");
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

FlipkartDbConfig

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

/**
 * Configuration class for Flipkart DB
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="flipkart.mongodb")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.flipkart"}, mongoTemplateRef="flipkartMongoTemplate")
public class FlipkartDbConfig extends AbstractMongoDbConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlipkartDbConfig.class);

    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="flipkartMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Creating MongoTemplate for Flipkart DB");
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

Notice that each of these configuration class is creating its own MongoTemplate and it is enabling its own MongoRepository. Also one of these needs to be `@Primary` otherwise the spring boot will throw error. It doesn't matter which of these is primary; ultimately these will be connecting to their own repository

**4) Create entities and a repository for each DB.**

You need to create a repository for each DB now. Given that your collection is same for all the DBs, I have created following sample entity -

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

/**
 * Sample Entity class
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Document(collection="productDetails")
public class ProductDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field("productName")
    private String productName;

    @Field("productDesc")
    private String productDesc;

    @Field("productQuantity")
    private String productQuantity;

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getProductQuantity() {
        return productQuantity;
    }

    public void setProductQuantity(String productQuantity) {
        this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
    }

}
```

You can create/modify the entity class as per your collection details.

AmazonRepository

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.amazon;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity.ProductDetails;

/**
 * 
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Repository
public interface AmazonRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductDetails, ObjectId> {

}
```

FlipkartRepository

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.flipkart;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity.ProductDetails;

@Repository
public interface FlipkartRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductDetails, ObjectId> {

}
```

EbayRepository

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.repository.ebay;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity.ProductDetails;

/**
 * 
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
@Repository
public interface EbayRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductDetails, ObjectId> {

}
```

Again, each repository needs to be its own package otherwise there will be errors while running the application. This is the one disadvantage of this solution where you have to create as many repository packages as no of DBs you want to connect.

**5) Service implementation and connecting to different repositories**

ProductDetailsService Interface 
    package com.akash.mongo.multidb.service;

```
import com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity.ProductDetails;

/**
 * Sample interface with one add method
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
public interface ProductDetailsService {

    /**
     * 
     * @param productOrigin - the shop name i.e. Amazon, Flipkart or ebay.
     * @param productDetails - the product details to add
     */
    public void addProductDetails(String productOrigin, ProductDetails productDetails) throws RuntimeException;

}
```

ProductDetailsServiceImpl Class -

```
package com.akash.mongo.multidb.service;

import java.util.Map;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.akash.mongo.multidb.entity.ProductDetails;

/**
 * Implementation of ProductDetailsService interface
 * @author Akash
 *
 */
public class ProductDetailsServiceImpl implements ProductDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    /*
     * Spring boot will autowire all the repositories along with their name
     * amazonRepository - amazon repository instance
     * ebayRepository - ebay repository instance and so on
     */
    @Autowired
    Map<String, MongoRepository<ProductDetails, ObjectId>> repositories;

    @Override
    public void addProductDetails(String productOrigin, ProductDetails productDetails) throws RuntimeException {

        logger.info("Adding product details into {} db", productOrigin);

        //if productOrigin is Amazon; repositoryName will be amazonRepository which is already present in spring boot
        String repositoryName = productOrigin.toLowerCase()+"Repository";

        if(repositories.containsKey(repositoryName)) {
            repositories.get(repositoryName).save(productDetails);
        } else  {
            logger.error("{} shop is undefined in DB. Check and try again", productOrigin);
            throw new RuntimeException("Shop doesnot exist in MongoDb");
        }



    }

}
```

ProductOrigin you can derive from your request or headers whatever information is available to you.

**6) Lastly, application.properties**

Change the database, username and password details for each DB. Try not to use Admin credentials; Instead create username & password for each DB separately and update application.properties.

```
#MongoDb connection properties for Flipkart DB
flipkart.mongodb.database=flipkart
flipkart.mongodb.host=http://127.0.0.1
flipkart.mongodb.port=27017
flipkart.mongodb.username=flipkart
flipkart.mongodb.password=flipkart

#MongoDb connection properties for Amazon DB
amazon.mongodb.database=amazon
amazon.mongodb.host=http://127.0.0.1
amazon.mongodb.port=27017
amazon.mongodb.username=amazon
amazon.mongodb.password=amazon

#MongoDb connection properties for ebay DB
ebay.mongodb.database=ebay
ebay.mongodb.host=http://127.0.0.1
ebay.mongodb.port=27017
ebay.mongodb.username=ebay
ebay.mongodb.password=ebay
```

Now, if you need to add any new database, you just need to add one config class similar to AmazonDbConfig, one more package with the required repositories for that DB and connection details in application.properties. No change is required in service till your collection is same for all the DBs.

If you have multiple collections, you can add entity and repository for each collection (group all the respositories for single shop in one package) and solution should still hold good.

Comment: No problem! :-)